# Sum of the factors or the factorization?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does $(n+m)+(n-m)=2n$ where the product $(n+m)\times(n-m)$ is the difference of two squares refer to the sum of the factors or the sum of the factorization? The first and second cases sum to $2n$, but when factored the second does not. Further, is it necessary for the sum of the factorization of $n,m$ at some point to equal $2n$ where $n\gt3$?

$n=37,m=6$ 
$37^2-6^2=1333=43\times31$ 
$43+31=74=2n$

$n=37,m=4$ 
$37^2-4^2=1353=41\times33$ 
$41+3+11\neq74=2n$

Comment: Here is my interpretation of the question.
Find all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $2n = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i\alpha_i$, given $$n^2-m^2 = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{\alpha_i}$$
where $p$ is a prime.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use $(n+m)$ and $(n-m)$ as the factors. You can not further factorise it.

Because, $(n+m)+(n-m)=2n\ne (n+m)+3+\frac {n-m}{3}$

$n^2-m^2=(n+m)(n-m)$ Then, $(n+m)+(n-m)=2n$ and this valid $\forall n,m \in \mathbb R$

Your question,

> "Does (n+m)+(n−m)=2n
> where the product (n+m)×(n−m)
> is the difference of two squares refer to the sum of the factors or the sum of the factorization?"

Answer is no. Only $(n+m)+(n-m)=2n$, not sum of all factors.

Your example,

$n=37,m=4$

$37^2-4^2=1353=41\times33$

$41+33=74=2n\ne 41+3+11$

Comment: @O M But if the factorization and the factors are the same it gives the same result. I'm asking if there exists such an $(n+m)$ and $(n-m)$ for any $n\gt3$.

Comment: If you add $(n+m),(n-m)$ you always get $2n$ for any $n$ not only $n \ge 3$ .